# Two-place position predicate problem

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I see this sentence in one Logic Note Tutorial.

What arguments are involved in any situation is determined by the meaning of the predicate. Sleeping can only involve one argument, whereas placing naturally involves three. We can distinguish predicates in terms of how many arguments they involve: sleep is a one-place predicate, see is a two-place predicate involving two arguments and place is a three-place predicate.

Suppose P is a Two-place position predicate, and have:

[image]

> > all models of $\varphi$ is infinite.

I try to check the validity of this sentence, but failed. infact I think this is false, but no idea.

Comment: oops, [sleeping can be a two-place predicate!](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268726/are-there-real-life-relations-which-are-symmetric-and-reflexive-but-not-transiti/268732#268732) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tru with a domain $D = \{ a, b \}$ with only two elements, and try to satisfy the formula [you will not succeed ...].

Then try with a domain $D = \{ a_n \}_{n < \omega}$ , with $n$ whatever, and perform the same check : again the answer will be negative.

In this way, you will convince ourself that the formula is not *satisfiable* in a finite domain.

Finally, check it with the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers*, with the usual ordering : $<$, and you will find that the above formula is *satisfiable*.

Comment: Dear @Mauro, can we say above sentence is True? or it's better to say $\varphi$ has finite and infinite model?

Comment: @JosiVerona - NO; I'm saying that you will **not** succeed with a *finite* amount of elements in the domain, whatever big it will be. Please, try with a finite $n$ (not so big ...). The only possibility is with an *infinite* domain, like $\mathbb N$ (clearly, the example is "manufactured" having in mind $\mathbb N$). Thus, the sentence : "all models of $\varphi$ are infinite" is **TRUE**.

Comment: @JosiVerona - try with the simple exercise with $D = \{ 1,2,3 \}$. Clearly, not $P(1,1), P(2,2), P(3,3)$, by the first part of the formula. Then, by the last part, there must be some $x$ for which $P(1,x)$ holds: call it $2$; and again for $2$. But it cannot be $P(2,1)$, otherwise by the "middle" part, we will have that $P(1,2)$ and $P(2,1)$ will give $P(1,1)$, contrary to first part. Then we must have $P(2,3)$. And now what happens with $P(3,x)$ ? It cannot be $P(3,3)$, nor $P(3,2)$ nor $P(3,1)$ (because from $P(1,2)$ and $P(2,3)$, $P(1,3)$ follows)), and thus where we can find the $x$ s.t.

Comment: $P(3,x)$ holds (in order to satisfy the part : $\forall x \exists y P(x,y)$) ? We need a fourth element ... And so on *ad infinitum*.

Comment: Dear Mauro, thanks in advance, I learn it.