# Give me an example of a relation.

Tags: relations

Give me an example of a relation which is:

(i) Reflexive and Symmetric but not Transitive.

(ii)Symmetric and Transitive but not Reflexive.

I'm confused because I think a Ref. and Sym. relation must be Tra. and a Sym. and Tra. relation must be Ref. but I can't prove it. (can't express in rigorous detail, but intutive conjecture seems right.)

**Edit 12/2**
Example:
(ii) If (a,b)$\in$R then (b,a)$\in$R by symmetric-ity and so by transitivity if (a,b)$\in$R and (b,a)$\in$R $\implies$(a,a)$\in$R so doesn't R become reflexive?

Comment: Perhaps you might preface your question with "Please"

Comment: @Andrew i can't judge if it fits here since it's not my tounge ;)

Comment: $(i)$ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268726/are-there-real-life-relations-which-are-symmetric-and-reflexive-but-not-transiti  
$(ii)$ the first comment to the OP of above link

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(i) The 'has eaten lunch with' relation **on the set of all people**.

(ii) **On the set of all people**.  Two people are related if they were both born in the year 1985.

Comment: Surely $(ii)$ is reflexive?!

Comment: @GFauxPas: No because if you weren't born in 1985, then you're not related to yourself (reflexivity is a universal property that must hold for all elements of the set--i.e. $x$ must be related to $x$ for all $x$).

Comment: Oh whoops, I misinterpreted. Thanks.

Comment: if you aren't born in 1985 then you can't have a relation!

Comment: @ADG: Not all elements have to be related to anything.  And in fact you need such elements for an example of type (ii)--because for any $x$, if $x$ is related to (some) $y$, then by symmetry $y$ is related to $x$, and then by transitivity $x$ is related to $x$.

Comment: OK             ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Using a formal procedure, consider the set $S = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$ and the relation $$R = \{ (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2), (2,1), (2,3), (3,2) \}$$ Then $R$ is reflexive and symmetric but not transitive, as $(1,2), (2,3) \in R$, but $(1,3) \not\in R$.

I am sure you can now construct an example for case ii.

Comment: actually (2,3)$\in$R

Comment: edited to add counterexample which you are not trying to answer.