# Prove that $(A,B)\sim(P,Q)$ and $(C,D)\sim (P,Q)\implies (A,B)\sim (C,D)$?

Tags: proof-verification, analytic-geometry

I have the following laws:

> [image]

And I did the following:

- $(A,B)\sim(P,Q)\wedge (C,D)\sim (P,Q) \stackrel{?}{\implies} (A,B)\sim (C,D)$
- $(A,B)\sim(P,Q)\wedge \stackrel{symmetry}{(P,Q)\sim (C,D)}\stackrel{?}{\implies} (A,B)\sim (C,D)$
- $(A,B)\sim(P,Q)\wedge (P,Q)\sim (C,D) \implies (A,B)\sim (C,D)$

I guess this is it. Am I missing something? Also, is transitivity actually needed? It seems to be only a variant of symmetry, I guess that only symmetry is needed to show transitivity but I may be wrong.

Comment: Seems correct. You do need transitivity for the last step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
(A,B) \sim (P,Q) \text{ and } (C,D) \sim (P,Q) & \overset{(b)}\implies (A,B) \sim (P,Q) \text{ and } (P,Q) \sim (C,D) \\
& \overset{(c)}\implies (A,B) \sim (C,D)
\end{align}
In general, transitivity can't be shown from symmetry, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268726/are-there-real-life-relations-which-are-symmetric-and-reflexive-but-not-transiti).