# Why do we even need transitivity?

Tags: logic, definition

I am referring to two Peano axioms:

If $x = y$ then $y = x$ (symmetry)

If $x = y$ and $y = z$ then $x = z$ (transitivity)

What I don't understand is why we need the transitive axiom. Isn't it already implied by the symmetry axiom? Is it more of a convenience? Can we prove that transitivity is a required axiom? What happens if we were to remove it?

Or should I think of this more like "symmetry just says we can physically flip the order of the equalities, and transitivity lets us swap things around as long as they're all equal to each other"?

Comment: Why would symmetry imply transitivity?

Comment: If $2+2 = 4$ then $4 = 2+2$. If $2+2 = 1+3$ then $1+3=2+2$. Either way we've shown that $2+2$ is equal to either $4$ or $1+3$ (and vice-versa), so this implies $4 = 1+3$ too

Comment: I kissed john, john kissed mike. How did I kiss mike?

Comment: @user537069 You are _assuming_ transitivity when you make that conclusion.

Comment: You're using transitivity implicitly there. I recommend searching for "equivalence relations" to see why the axioms are necessary.

Comment: @TyCobb Those aren't statements of equality though, just distinct elements acting on each other.

Comment: The peano axioms are defining equality as an equivalence relation. You can't use properties of equality before you define it.

Comment: Does transitivity include symmetry? If I am allowed to swap things around then shouldn't transitivity let me swap $x=y$ with $y=x$? I want to understand why we need both axioms and what happens if we remove one of them.

Comment: @user537069 No. If $x<y$ and $y<z$, then $x<z$. But $x<y$ does not mean $y<x$.

Comment: [A related question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268726)

Comment: @immibis You misread something. My comment had nothing to do with Ty’s kissing relation

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Consider the following relation: $x$ **opposes** $y$ if and only if $x = -y$.

Can you see that the "opposes" relation is symmetrical but not transitive?

Comment: No, I don't see this. What do you mean? If $x = -y$ and $-y = z$ then $x = z$ seems correct to me

Comment: @user537069 But $x$ does not _oppose_ $z$. We are considering the relation _oppose_ here.

Comment: So $x$ opposes $y$ and $y$ opposes $z$, but $x$ does not oppose $z$, so transitivity fails here and we can only speak in terms of symmetry: $x$ opposes $y$ and $y$ opposes $x$.

Comment: @user537069 And most importantly, symmetry does not imply transitivity. Therefore you need both axioms for a meaningful definition of equality.

Comment: Does transitivity imply symmetry?

Comment: @user537069
Not at all. Consider the "less than" relation.

Comment: You got an answer to that question from @bames.

Comment: Is there a way to prove the necessity of these axioms logically without the use of things like "opposing" and "less-than/greater-than" counterexamples? Or is it just that these are the axioms and they either apply/don't apply to various kinds of comparisons?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want a counterexample? There are many more, but one counterexample is already sufficient for a proof.

Comment: @ChrisRandall I am fine with counterexamples, but I am curious if there is a way I could have shown the necessity of these things from logic alone rather than reliance on specific cases.

Comment: @user537069 A proof would be necessary if the transitivity axiom *were to imply* the symmetry axiom. The counterexamples are actually a proof that no such proof can be produced.

Comment: Interesting... thanks everyone! This has been very enlightening

Comment: @user537069 Keep in mind that a counter example *is* a logical proof: $\because A \to B,\quad \because \neg B,\quad \therefore \neg A$.

Comment: In this specific example, $A$ is "Symmetry implies transitivity", and $B$ is "All symmetric relations are transitive"

Answer (score 22):

Some relations are symmetric without being transitive.

For  example if John and Jill are friends and Jill and Jeff are friends, it does not imply that John and Jeff are friends.

So friendship is a relation which is symmetric but not transitive.

Mathematically speaking, in geometry perpendicularity is symmetric but not transitive.

We like the relation $x=y$ be both symmetric and transitive.

Comment: Are there any examples of relationships that are neither transitive nor symmetric?

Comment: X is a parent of Y?

Comment: Parenthood is neither symmetric nor transitive. If  x is the father of y, then y is not the father of x. And if x is the father of y and y is the father of z, then x is not the father of z.

Comment: "Ancestor" is the transitive relation, not "Parent". If X is an ancestor of Y and Y is an ancestor of Z, then X is an ancestor of Z. (At least grandparent, obviously)

Comment: Ancestor is an example of a relationship that's transitive but not symmetric. Sibling would be an example of a relationship that's both symmetric and transitive. So we have examples of all the combinations in families.

Comment: @Barmar I have a brother named James.  So, James is my sibling, and I am also James's sibling.  Does that mean that I am my own sibling?

Comment: @mathmandan Good point. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYlJH81dSiw

Comment: @user537069 in the finite case, once you get beyond sets with just a few elements, the vast majority of relations are neither transitive nor symmetric

Answer (score 7):

It's easy to write down an example of a symmetric relation which fails to satisfy transitivity: on the set $\{a,b,c\}$ we say that $a \sim b$ and $b \sim a$ and $b \sim c$ and $c \sim b$ (I'm using a different symbol $\sim$ so as not to confuse the issue). So no, the symmetry axiom does not imply the transitivity axiom.

Perhaps you might want to think of the transitive law as it is stated in some translations of Euclid: thing which are equal to the same thing are equal to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Another example of a relationship which is symmetric but not transitive: computer floating point arithmetic is approximate, so for example `(1./3.)*3. != 1.0` (some rounding occurs when the division is done, and this destroys the equality).  It is thus important when comparing floating point results for equality to compare with an appropriate margin of error.  Deciding what this margin should be is a *hard* problem, but let us use a margin of 0.1:

Then 0.61 is near 0.7 and 0.7 is near 0.61 (symmetric), but whereas 0.7 is near 0.79, 0.61 is *not* near 0.79 (not transitive).

Answer (score 1):

Other answers cover very well why we need a transitivity axiom in the case of axiomatised Peano arithmetic.

But it's worth considering: why does this not feel necessary for the *equality* relation? The following idea may underly your intuition.

In many logics, we have an additional rule of 'substitution' or 'substitutivity'. Sometimes it's considered an axiom, sometimes a rule part of the logic, and sometimes an axiom schema (for example sometimes in First Order Logic, in which the second order axiom given below can not be written). Read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) on Wikipedia.

It looks something like this:

For all variables $x$ and $y$ and for all formulae $P$, if we know $x = y$ and we know $P(x)$ then we know $P(y)$.

One way to write it as a second order statement is this:

$\forall P. \forall x. \forall y. x = y \implies P(x) \implies P(y)$.

Interestingly, once we have this axiom, logical rule, or axiom schema in place, all that is required to derive the other properties of equality is Reflexivity.

The derivation of Symmetry relies on the observation that an application of the substitution rule with $P$ as $w \mapsto w = x$ gives us

$\forall x. \forall y. x = y \implies x = x \implies y = x$.

The derivation of Transitivity relies on observation that an application of the substitution rule with $P$ as $w \mapsto w = z$ gives us

$\forall x. \forall y. x = y \implies x = z \implies y = z$.