# Existence of reflexive, symmetric and intransitive relations on sets containing more than one element

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, relations

Are there any examples of reflexive, symmetric and intransitive relations on sets containing more than one element (not explicitly defined by their elements?
(edited due to imprecision, I apologize.)

Comment: Have you tried to find some example on sets with 2 or 3 elements for example?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268726/are-there-real-life-relations-which-are-symmetric-and-reflexive-but-not-transiti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a big class of examples, consider an undirected graph $G$ on a set of vertices $V$, and say two vertices $v_1, v_2 \in V$ are related if $v_1=v_2$ or there is an edge from $v_1$ to $v_2$ in $G$.

This defines a reflexive, symmetric relation on $V$, but will not typically be transitive. (It *will* be transitive if $G$ is complete, or a union of complete subgraphs, but not in general.)

Comment: Thank you @Clive Newstead! I even forgot to write I was looking for relations that are not necessarily defined by their elements counted, but you gave me an interesting answer anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  How about $R=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3), (1,2), (2,1), (2,3), (3,2)\}$ on $\{1,2,3\}$?

It's reflexive because of $(1,1), (2,2), $ and $(3,3)$, and it's symmetric,

but it's not transitive, because $(1,2),(2,3)\in R$ but $(1,3)\not\in R$.

---

**Addendum in response to edit of the question:**

If you want such a relation defined with some properties,

rather than explicitly in terms of the elements,

define $(x,y)\in R\;$ by $\;|x-y|\le1$.

Comment: W.Tanner, I forgot to ask (precisely), my big mistake, if there exist such relations defined with some operation or number properties.

Comment: @VerkhotsevaKatya:  you mean like $(x,y)\in R$ defined by $|x-y|\le1$ ?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I have totally forgotten it.