# Possible examples of real life membership relations that are non-transitive ( not necessarily intransitive)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, relations

My question is not the same as this one : [Are there real-life relations which are symmetric and reflexive but not transitive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268726/are-there-real-life-relations-which-are-symmetric-and-reflexive-but-not-transiti). ***The answer " x has slept with y " was a good answer to this question ( more that 120 upvotes) . It wouldn't do for mine.***

I'm not asking for arbitrary relations having such and such properties.

I'm looking for real life relations having a conceptual analogy with " membership". ***So here , the conceptual content of the examples  am asking for really matters.***

---

- Let's admit, if you please, for the sake of the question, that the membership relation can hold between a concrete object and a set of concrete objects ( in spite of the fact that, properly, it only holds between sets, due to the fact that, in set theory, every object dealt with is a  set).

I'm looking for real life analogous cases of the fact that the membership relation is *not* transitve.

- Maybe these ones :

(1) I am a member a football club. My football club belongs to a football league. But I am not a member of the football league.

(2) I am a british citizen, meaning that I belong to the british poeple. We are, say,  in 1943, so currently the british people belongs to the Allies.  But I am not one of the Allies.

(3) Letter ' $a$ ' belongs to the word ' cat'. The word ' cat' belongs to the sentence ' the cat is on the map'. But letter ' a ' is not a member of the sentence ' the cat is on the map'. ( Arguably, a sentence is not a set of letters, nor of sounds, but a set of words).

- ***I'm not totally satisfied with these examples. For they instantiate intransitivity, rather that non-transitivity strictly speaking.***

Can you think of cases illustrating non-transitivity, I mean, the fact that in case $aRb$ and $bRc$ is true, $aRc$ can be true, but does not always nor automatically follow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there real-life relations which are symmetric and reflexive but not transitive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268726/are-there-real-life-relations-which-are-symmetric-and-reflexive-but-not-transiti)

Comment: Family relations are often intransitive: x is child of y and y is child of z, but x is not child of z.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos. Thanks for the link. My question is rather different though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. My friend Jane and I are both members of the Mathematics faculty at NoName University. NoName is an institutional member of the Gondwanaland Mathematical Society (the GMS). Jane's a member of the GMS, but I'm not.
2. Israel and Palestine are members of UNESCO. UNESCO is one of the constituent bodies of the United Nations. Israel is a member of the UN, but Palestine isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide two programming examples twice. They are not about the "real"/physical world, as programming languages are abstractions invented by humans, but they illustrate the non-transitive property you want.

In the [Smalltalk-80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) programming language, every Class is an Object, but not every Object is a Class. This language has an intricate [metaclass hierarchy](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Smalltalk_80_metaclasses.svg) (which you are invited to check in order to follow this explanation), which determines the following facts:

1. 'Hello, world!' is an Object.
2. Object is a Class.
3. However, 'Hello, world!' is not a Class. (It is just an ordinary
   non-class object.)

And also the following facts:

1. String is an Object.
2. Object is a Class.
3. String is a Class.

Explanation:

- *String* is a direct instance of *String class*, which extends *Object class*, which extends *Class*, which extends *ClassDescription*, which extends *Behavior*, which extends *Object*. Therefore, *String* is an (indirect) instance of *Object*.
- *Object* is a direct instance of *Object class*, which extends *Class*. Therefore, *Object* is an (indirect) instance of *Class*.
- (Reiterating part of the initial bullet point:) *String* is a direct instance of *String class*, which extends *Object class*, which extends *Class*. Therefore, *String* is an (indirect) instance of *Class*.

Regarding the *'Hello, world!'* string:

- *'Hello, world!'* is a direct instance of *String*, which extends *Object*. Therefore, *'Hello, world!'* is an (indirect) instance of *Object*.
- However, *'Hello, world!'* is not an (indirect) instance of *Class*, as *Object* does not extend *Class*.

In the [Java programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), the facts are similar. Only the explanation differs as Java has a [much simpler metaclass hierarchy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html):

- *String* is a direct instance of *Class*, which extends *Object*. Therefore, *String* is an (indirect) instance of *Object*.
- *Object* is a direct instance of *Class*.
- (Reiterating part of the initial bullet point:) *String* is a direct instance of *Class*.

Regarding the *"Hello, world!"* string in Java, the explanation is identical to the one provided for the *'Hello, world!'* string in Smalltalk-80.

All these facts can be made visible by running the following Java source code:

```
//https://replit.com/languages/java10
public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    System.out.println("\"Hello, world!\" is a direct instance of: " + "Hello, world!".getClass());
    //System.out.println("\"Hello, world!\" extends: " + "Hello, world!".getSuperclass()); //uncommenting it fails: "Hello, world!" is not a class
    System.out.println("String extends: " + String.class.getSuperclass());
    System.out.println("Is \"Hello, world!\" an (indirect) instance of Object? " + ("Hello, world!" instanceof Object));
    System.out.println("String is a direct instance of: " + String.class.getClass());
    System.out.println("Class is a direct instance of: " + Class.class.getClass());
    System.out.println("Class extends: " + Class.class.getSuperclass());
    System.out.println("Is String an (indirect) instance of Object? " + (String.class instanceof Object));
    System.out.println("Is Class an (indirect) instance of Object? " + (Class.class instanceof Object));
    System.out.println("Object is a direct instance of: " + Object.class.getClass());
    System.out.println("Is Object an (indirect) instance of Object? " + (Object.class instanceof Object));
    System.out.println("Object extends: " + Object.class.getSuperclass());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
"Hello, world!" is a direct instance of: class java.lang.String
String extends: class java.lang.Object
Is "Hello, world!" an (indirect) instance of Object? true
String is a direct instance of: class java.lang.Class
Class is a direct instance of: class java.lang.Class
Class extends: class java.lang.Object
Is String an (indirect) instance of Object? true
Is Class an (indirect) instance of Object? true
Object is a direct instance of: class java.lang.Class
Is Object an (indirect) instance of Object? true
Object extends: null
```