# How to motivate the teaching of relations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, relations, education

I am teaching an introduction to pure maths module. Are there any really good resources on relations? I want something that will have an impact and motivate the learner. I am not really looking for artificial engineering examples but some bona fide real applications.

Comment: I don't understand why you need there to be an outside resource... relations are used all the time in everyday life with or without the use of mathematical language.  "Is bigger than"... "Lives near"... "Shares a property with..." and so on are all examples of relations you'd see.  Surely you can come up with thousands of more specific examples if you tried.

Comment: Have you ever opened a bag of m&m's?  You can organize the candies by color.  How did you do that?  A relation... specifically the equivalence relation where two candies are compared favorably if they are the same color...

Comment: Cf. [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/18801/whats-the-point-of-learning-equivalence-relations) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268726/are-there-real-life-relations-which-are-symmetric-and-reflexive-but-not-transiti)